# gRPC microservices communication in kubernates

Tags: rest, go, kubernetes, devops, grpc

## gRPC client server communcation in local

In .env of client I give the port number `SERVER=:50051`, client make the request to server using using os.Getenv("SERVER")

## REST client server communcation in kubernates

I expose the server like this `http://cloud-order-web:9005`
In .env of client put this key and value `ORDER_SERVER=http://cloud-order-web:9005`,
client make the request to server using os.Getenv("ORDER_SERVER")+"/order/items"

## How does gRPC client server communication in kubernates ?

how can gRPC client and server pods communicate inside kubernates ?
how can I expose a gRPC server to be called by clients ? gRPC does not follow http protocols, then how should endpoint of gRPC server looks like ? I could not find any resources.

## Can I expose gRPC server with url path like in REST

is it possible to expose gRPC server like this (http://localhost:8000/order/items) without using gRPC gateway plugins ?

I have written the codes of server and clients in Go, working fine in local, not working in kubernates, client is unable to call gRPC server.
Mine Devops guy does not have any idea of gRPC, I am asking for resources to how expose a gRPC server and call by client in kubernates.

Answer (score 0):

You expose it like before, just don't add the `http://` at the begining.
For example:

```golang
conn, err := grpc.Dial("localhost:8080", grpc.WithTransportCredentials(insecure.NewCredentials()))
```

It's the same for services, just put the service address.

```
conn, err := grpc.Dial("svc-name.namespace.svc.cluster.local:8080", grpc.WithTransportCredentials(insecure.NewCredentials()))
```

Just create a service with `TCP` protocol and ports you want.

Comment: `cloudOrderServer := os.Getenv("ORDER_SERVER");
connection, connectionErr := grpc.Dial(cloudOrderServer, grpc.WithInsecure(), grpc.WithBlock());`  we are not using security certifications for now.

Comment: That's fine my point was something else. connections options are up to you. My point was address actually.